# append after clicked event not working - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to have simple tooltip in AngularJS.

here is my html:

```
<span class="afterme" ng-mouseover="showToolTip('this is something', $event)" ng-mouseleave="hideToolTip();">
   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" ></i>
</span>
```

hrere is JS:

```
$scope.showToolTip = function(text,$event){
            console.log($event);
            console.log($event.currentTarget.className);

var abc = $event.currentTarget.className;
angular.element(abc).append('<p class="tooltip2">' + text + '</p>');

};
```

Nothing happening there, no tooltip showing, there is class printed  `afterme` in the console.

Its working fine when I use below code (appending to body):

```
var body = angular.element(document).find('body');
body.append(...);
```

Comment: This is an anti-pattern in angular. The way you need to do it is to actually have the tooltip in the DOM hidden and make it visible using ng-show/ng-if when some scope state changes based on your mouse overs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I got it solved, just changed `$event.currentTarget.className;` to `$event.target`

and `.append` to `.after` to avoid duplication tooltips.

so the code becomes:

```
$scope.showToolTip = function(text,$event){
     angular.element($event.target).after('<p class="tooltip2">' +text+ '</p>');
};
$scope.hideToolTip = function($event) {
     angular.element(document).find('.tooltip2').remove();
};
```

html remains same.

Let me know If I have added simplest custom tooltip in AngularJS :)

Here is the CSS:

```
.tooltip2 {
        display:block;
        position:absolute;
        border:1px solid #333;
        background-color:#161616;
        border-radius:5px;
        padding:10px;
        color:#fff;
        font-size:12px Arial;
    }
```

Working fine now

Answer (score 0):

angular.element with jqlite does not do element selection, as far as I can tell from the docs. That means angular.element(abc) does not work, (though this should be angular.element('.'+abc) anyway)event

$event.currentTarget is, however, a reference to the actual html node, which means you can do `angular.element($event.currentTarget).append('<p class="tooltip2">' + text + '</p>');};`

Keep in mind, though, this is not the correct way to do this in angular. You should never manipulate the DOM in a controller. Such things are reserved for directives.

A directive would give you direct access to the angular element (passed in via an argument in the link function) and allow you to bind the event you want there. Controllers should only be used for maintaining your data.

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('.className')).append(...);
```